# Server side SignalR hub IConnected and IDisconnect do not work

Tags: asp.net, websocket, signalr, signalr-hub

I just translated the sample code in [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs) to VB.NET as below. The `test` is called properly when I call it from client, but the server side `Connect`, `Disconnect`, and `Reconnect` are never called. Anything more I should do? I've tested with IE10, Chrome, and FF.

Edited: `$.connection.hub.disconnected` and `stateChanged` are working as I expect.

```
  Public Class Status
    Inherits Hub
    Implements IDisconnect
    Implements IConnected

    Public Function Disconnect() As Threading.Tasks.Task Implements IDisconnect.Disconnect
        Return Clients.leave(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString())
    End Function

    Public Function Connect() As Threading.Tasks.Task Implements IConnected.Connect
        Return Clients.joined(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString())
    End Function

    Public Function Reconnect(groups As IEnumerable(Of String)) As Threading.Tasks.Task Implements IConnected.Reconnect
        Return Clients.rejoined(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString())
    End Function

    Public Sub test()
        Stop
    End Sub

End Class
```